# AWS EC2 Instance fwrite: No space left on device

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am using an `g4dn.xlarge` instance on AWS with two volumes:

1. A 8GB default volume and
2. A 50GB second volume that I have successfully attached and mounted to the instance as confirmed by `df -h`

Once I then try to install anaconda, I successfully download the installer of my preferred version with `wget` but once I try to run the bash file I get the error
`OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device
[1883] Failed to execute script entry_point
Failed to write all bytes for lib/python3.7/config-3.7m-x86_64-linux-gnu/Makefile
fwrite: No space left on device`

The question is: What more should i do to enable the installation happen in the second volume that I have already mounted?

Comment: Ok, so the issue appears to be that the root partition == 8GB is full

Answer (score 0):

So, we have two options:

1. You can follow [THIS GUIDE](https://linuxacademy.com/blog/linux/resizing-root-partition-on-linux-in-amazon-ec2/) in order to expand the size of the root partition. The way it works is that you stop the instance, you create a snapshot of the root volume and then you create a new volume from that instance but of bigger size, then attach it to the instance and launch the instance. It should be fine but didn't work for me
2. Create a new instance but with a bigger root partition size from the beginning